# Чи українське слово "виїмка" як юридичний термін?

Tags: терміни, росіянізм, legal-terms

[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyjimka) зазначає наступні значення слова **"виїмка"**.

> **ВИ́ЇМКА**, и, жін.
>   1. **Невелика заглибина, западина у чому-небудь**. *Вони знову оглянули знайому дорогу, на якій було вивчено кожен камінь, виїмку і поворот
>   (Василь Кучер, Чорноморці, 1956, 307)*...
>
> //  **Заглибина, зроблена способом виймання, вирізування і т. ін.**
>   частини чого-небудь звідкись. *За тунелем пішов глибокий арик — виїмка
>   аж до північного тунелю (Іван Ле, Міжгір'я, 1953, 246)*...
>
> 2. заст. **Те саме, що виняток**. *4 збірники моїх новел, видані «Видавничою Спілкою», обнімають усі мої опубліковані досі новели, з
>      виїмкою 3-х оповідань для дітей (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956,
>      287)*.
> 3. кул. **Інструмент, яким роблять заглибини в продуктах або кулінарних виробах**. *Для нарізання картоплі у формі стружки.. застосовують
>      спеціальні ножі, а для вирізування кульок — виїмки різних розмірів
>      (Технологія приготування їжі, 1957, 22).*
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 402.

Однак, стаття [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0) пропонує додаткові сфери застосування цього слова:

> `Виїмка` — процес виймання корисних копалин у гірничій справі
>
> `Виїмка` — термін у логістиці
>
> `Виїмка` — термін у кримінальній справі
>
> `Виїмка` — невелика заглибина, западина у чому-небудь, геометрична
>   фігура у надрах землі (траншея, котлован тощо)

Дивно, що попри відсутність відповідного значення у Словнику української мови (в 11 томах),  а також у [Словнику Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/), термін `"виїмка"` дійсно використовується в законодавсті, зокрема [кримінальному](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/4651-17/page?text=%E2%E8%BF%EC%EA), а також [нотаріальному](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/rada/show/3425-12?nreg=3425-12&find=1&text=%E2%E8%BF%EC%EA&x=11&y=5#w11).

Хтось знає, коли і на якій підставі в українське законодавство увійшла очевидна калька від російського **`"выемка"`**, а також чи є в якихось інших  (може, спеціалізованих юридичних) словниках більш адекватний український відповідник?

Comment: `У разі невиконання ухвали про тимчасовий доступ до речей і документів слідчий суддя, якій надано право на доступ до речей і документів на підставі ухвали, має право постановити ухвалу про дозвіл на проведення обшуку, з метою відшукання та вилучення зазначених речей і документів, відповідно до положень ст. 166 КПК України;` витяг з реальної ухвали, 2016 рік, м. Київ.

Comment: [Витяг з КПК України](http://kodeksy.com.ua/kpku-2012/166.htm) від 2012 року  1. `У разі невиконання ухвали про тимчасовий доступ до речей і документів слідчий суддя, суд за клопотанням сторони кримінального провадження, якій надано право на доступ до речей і документів на підставі ухвали, має право постановити ухвалу про дозвіл на проведення обшуку згідно з положеннями цього Кодексу з метою відшукання та вилучення зазначених речей і документів.` Як бачите використовується _вилучення_.

Comment: @Gluttton я вам більше скажу, у КПК є окрема ціла *"Глава 16. Тимчасове вилучення майна"*, але поряд з цим є *"Глава 15. Тимчасовий доступ до речей і документів"*, де в ст. 159 зустрічається *"виїмка"*,  а також ст. 258-262 (*"виїмка кореспонденції"*), А у ЗУ "Про нотаріат (ст. 8-1) вживаються паралельно  - *"вилучення (виїмка)"*. Як бачите, використовується не тільки *вилучення*, а й *виїмка*. Плутанина в термінології ще та. Посилання на повні версії чинних КПК і ЗУ "Про нотаріат" - в самому запитанні.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

СУМ-20 має таке означення (цікаво що порядок значень також змінено у порівнянні з СУМ-11):

> [ВИ́ЇМКА](http://test.ulif.org.ua:8000/expl/Entry/index?wordid=8943&page=0), и, ж.
>   1. Невелика заглибина, западина в чому-небудь.
>   2. Інструмент, яким роблять заглибини в продуктах або кулінарних виробах.
>   **3. юр. Вилучення предметів і документів при обшуку, перевірці, дослідженні.**
>   *Обшук і виїмка в приміщеннях, що їх займають підприємства, установи й організації, здійснюються в присутності їх представників (з наук. літ.).*
>   4. заст. Те саме, що ви́няток.

---

Не знаю наскільки сьогодні можна користуватися саме цим словником, але Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов) спеціально підкреслює це значення як юридичне:

> Вы́емка и вы́ем –
>
> 1. вийма́ння;
> 2. (в одежде) ви́кот;
> 3. **(при обыске) ви́їмка;**
> 4. архит. – рівчачо́к, жолобо́к;
> 5. (в земле) ви́їмка, вріз. [В залізни́чих врі́зах (Тутк.)].

Хоча [інші словники](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) того періоду пропонують інші переклади з російської:

Російсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р. (М. Дорошенко, М. Станиславський, В. Страшкевич):

> **Выемка (конфискованное при обыске)** – вийняток (-тку); (действие) – вийма́ння, вийняття, конфіска́ція; в. писем (из почтового ящика) производится – вийма́ють листи.

Російсько-український словник військової термінології 1928р. (С. та О. Якубські)

> Выем, выемка — вийма́ння, ви́йма, -ми; В. для защелки — ви́йма на за́щіпку; В. железнодорожная — залівни́ча ви́йма; В. кольцевой — кільце́ва ви́йма; **В. суми — вийма́ння гроше́й.**

Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)

> Вы́емка = 1. вийма́ння. 2. (в одежї) — ви́кот (С. Аф.), ви́різка, ви́тин (С. Пар.). — Керсетка з великим викотом. **3. трус (С. Л. Ш.), трусани́на, реви́зия.** (Гал.). Власне такий трус, коли знайдено і забрано утїкача, чи злодїя, що переховував ся, або що небудь заборонене, покрадене або що. 4. (в будові) — жолобо́к, рівчачо́к. 5. (в землї) — ви́їмка.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь Як на мене, калька калькою. Лиш узаконена в новому словнику у зв'язку з використанням навіть у законодавстві. Цікавий факт до речі: двомовні словники містили значення, якого не було в академічному словнику української мови, використання поширилося на законодавчі документи, відтак значення додалося в новий академічний словник.

Answer (score -1):

Схоже на те, що оби два слова і `вилучення` і `виїмка` є українськими. Але застосовуються у різних контекстах, так наприклад `вилучення здійснюється уповноваженним слідчим у підозрюванного`, а `виїмка осущєствляється уполномоченим слєдоватєлєм у підозрєваємого`.