# Чи існує механізм видалення слів з української мови?

Tags: language-regulation

Вже було питання про те, як нові слова [потрапляють до української мови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/684/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8). Але запитання про [слово "виїмка"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/697/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD) наштовнуло мене на ортогональне запитання: а чи є механізм видалення слів з української мови, які потрапили до неї помилково (наприклад, через помилки при складанні нормативних актів, тощо)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Жодна природна мова не має механізмів штучного "видалення" з неї "помилкових" слів: нормативні матеріали, такі як загальні та спеціальні словники, мають лише обмежений вплив, і тільки на відносно невелику підмножину мовників... Втім, систематична підтримка бажаних синонімів, виправлення помилок у відповідних текстах для нових видань тощо, роз'яснення діючим та майбутнім викладачам, чому краще вживати певні слова замість певних інших — все це сприяє "вимиванню" небажаних слів та зміцненню вкоріненості кращих зразків...

Comment: Дуже цікава річь виходить: я можу спілкуватись як мені заманеться (у т.ч. письмово) пояснюючи це тим, що це діалект/запозичення/інше і ці мої помилки будуть "розповзатись" і немає способа у який це все зупинити? Я знов про цю "виїмку".

Comment: @Gluttton, "розповзатись" помилки будуть тільки якщо інші мовники, велика їх кількість, підтримають, тобто будуть наслідувати їхнього автора ;)  Власне, приклади цього досить числені, але зазвичай пов'язані з певними штучними факторами